# MySQL query with multiple AND operators

Tags: mysql

This query is not working for me. Where have I done mistake. Please help

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE ( username='$myusername' and (password='$mypassword' and password='$encrypted_mypassword'))";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but this should work,

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE 
Username = '$myusername' AND
Password = '$mypassword' AND
Password = '$encrypted_mypassword'";
```

For what you are doing brackets are not required, and you are also trying to compare a single field to possibly 2 different values.

Comment: Try this,

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE
Username = '".$myusername."' AND
Password = '".$mypassword."' AND
Password = '".$encrypted_mypassword."'";

Also, make sure that all of your table names and columns are correct, are you getting an error? Or just no results?

Comment: I am getting correct value when i use username and password without encrypted password.. When I include encrypted password i am not getting it.

Comment: Yes, that is understandable. The way you are currently running this query, you are assuming that the variables $mypassword and $encrypted_mypassword contain the exact same value. Just by the looks of this it is a security hazard, having plain text passwords stored in the database, if you are trying to match up the non encrypted variable.

What you should have is an encryption algorithm, MD5, SHA1, etc, and store only the final encryption. To authenticate a user, re-encrypt the newly entered password and compare the the known encryption. No plain text passwords in database.

Answer (score 2):

I assuming you accepted both plain password and encrypted password. Try this...

```
SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' AND 
(password='$mypassword' OR  password='$encrypted_mypassword')
```

If encrypted password only, try this...

```
SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' AND 
password='$encrypted_mypassword'
```